# Doubt while applying Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I am computing the following integral.

> $\int_C \frac{\sin(\pi z^2)}{z-1}$, where $C$ is the circle $|z| = 1$.

Clearly $f(z) = \sin(\pi z^2)$ is analytic function on the given curve. I am confused which solution to be correct?

**Solution 1:** Since $z = 1$ lies on the boundary of the given curve $C$, given integral is zero  by using Cauchy theorem.

or

**Solution 2:** By using Cauchy integral formula value of given integral is $2\pi i f(1)$.

Thank you.

Comment: @Fabian I didn't understand. Please clarify my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution 2 doesn't look justified. The Cauchy integral formula that I learned is about integrals $\int_C(f(z)/(z-a))\,dz$ where $a$ lies in the **interior** of the region bounded by the contour of integration $C$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much for your reply. Does this means that solution one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z):=\frac{\sin(\pi z^2)}{z-1}$. Show that $f$ has in $z=1$ a removable singularity. Hence $f$ has an analytic continuation on all of $\mathbb C$. Therefore the integral $=0$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if in the denominator of $f(z)$ is $(z-1)^2$. In this case $z = 1$ would become pole of order $2$?

Comment: No. Let $g(z):=\frac{\sin(\pi z^2)}{(z-1)^2}$. Since $\sin(\pi z^2)$ has a zero of order $1$ at $z=1$, $g$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z=1$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Then what will be value of the integral in  this case? Sorry for my frequent question.

Comment: In this cases the integral is not defined

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.